# How to assign the result of execution of http client to 2 different variables ANDROID

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, connection

I apologize as this might be a very basic question. when i execute this code, the query in the php file is getting executed twice. This is because once the http client is executed and assigned to http response variable and second time to get the data from the php file .
please see the highlighted code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NfcRegisterationActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
TextView t;
Button submit;
EditText name,address, email,phone;  
HttpPost httppost;        
StringBuffer buffer;
HttpResponse response;
HttpClient httpclient;
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    name =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    address=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.address);
    email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
    phone =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.phone);
    submit =(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);

    submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try
            {
                httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/customersInsert.php");
                nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name.getText().toString().trim()));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone",phone.getText().toString().trim()));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email.getText().toString().trim()));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address", address.getText().toString().trim()));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                //Execute HTTP Post Request
                response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                String res = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
                t.setText("Response from PHP :"+ res);

            }catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }


    });


}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your post and REMOVE THE SHOUTING, as it makes your question very hard to read. Please use proper capitalization and punctuation. The easier you make your question to read and understand, the better your chances are of getting an answer. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the following?:

```
    response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
    ResponseHandler responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    String res = responseHandler.handleResponse(response);
    t.setText("Response from PHP :"+ res);
```

No need to call the execute function twice when you can declare your handler and call it's handleResponse function. Not sure why you need two variables if you're just trying to get the response text as a string. If you only need the response as text, you could do:

```
    ResponseHandler responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    String res = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
    t.setText("Response from PHP :"+ res);
```

According to the HttpClient documentation, if the the execute function is provided with a response handler it will return the response as the data type returned by the response handler.

Hope this helps.